# Can't create xml file

Tags: xml, vb.net

I can't seem to create an XML file. I am trying to create this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RFQsIssued xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Items>
        <Item ID="s1600" Sent="01/01/1980" UoM="Each"/>
        <Item ID="54322" Sent="02/02/1980" UoM="Each"/>
    </Items>
</RFQsIssued>
```

I've tried using this code:

```
    Document = New XmlDocument()
    Declaration = Document.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", Nothing)
    Document.AppendChild(Declaration)
    RFQsIssued = Document.CreateElement("RFQsIssued")

    'Makes a file, not the one I want, if I comment out these 4 lines
    Attribute = Document.CreateAttribute("xmlns", "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")
    RFQsIssued.Attributes.Append(Attribute)
    Attribute = Document.CreateAttribute("xmlns", "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")
    RFQsIssued.Attributes.Append(Attribute)

    Items = Document.CreateElement("Items")

    Item = Document.CreateElement("Item")
    Attribute = Document.CreateAttribute("ID")
    Attribute.InnerText = "s1600"
    Item.Attributes.Append(Attribute)
    Attribute = Document.CreateAttribute("Sent")
    Attribute.InnerText = "01/01/1980"
    Item.Attributes.Append(Attribute)
    Attribute = Document.CreateAttribute("UoM")
    Attribute.InnerText = "Each"
    Item.Attributes.Append(Attribute)
    Items.AppendChild(Item)

    Item = Document.CreateElement("Item")
    Attribute = Document.CreateAttribute("ID")
    Attribute.InnerText = "54322"
    Item.Attributes.Append(Attribute)
    Attribute = Document.CreateAttribute("Sent")
    Attribute.InnerText = "02/02/1980"
    Item.Attributes.Append(Attribute)
    Attribute = Document.CreateAttribute("UoM")
    Attribute.InnerText = "Each"
    Item.Attributes.Append(Attribute)
    Items.AppendChild(Item)

    RFQsIssued.AppendChild(Items)
    Document.AppendChild(RFQsIssued)
    Document.Save(Path)
```

But it produces an error on the `Save`:

> Cannot use a prefix with an empty namespace

When I comment out the first 2 attributes, it does produce a file, but not what I want.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RFQsIssued>
  <Items>
    <Item ID="s1600" Sent="01/01/1980" UoM="Each" />
    <Item ID="54322" Sent="02/02/1980" UoM="Each" />
  </Items>
</RFQsIssued>
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong? I know the dates are wrong, I think I can figure those out, but I can't get the attributes.

Comment: What programming language is that? What XML library are you using? Please add suitable tags to your question.

Comment: Why do you want to declare those `xmlns` prefixes? You don't use them at all.

Comment: @Quentin The language is VB.  I don't want to declare the xmlns prefixes, but that is the spec.

Answer (score 0):

One of the great features of VB.NET (and something which differentiates it from C#) is XML literals, which make manipulation of XML much more easy and less error-prone than building up by creating each attribute and element in code.  In your case, all you need to do is:

```
Dim doc As XDocument =
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <RFQsIssued xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Items>
            <Item ID="s1600" Sent="01/01/1980" UoM="Each"/>
            <Item ID="54322" Sent="02/02/1980" UoM="Each"/>
        </Items>
    </RFQsIssued>
```

You case use "<%=" and "%>" to substitute the value of a variable into the XML, either the inner text or an attribute, e.g.:

```
<Item ID=<%= item.Id %> Sent=<%= item.SentDate %> UoM="Each"/>
```

If you want to build up elements within a document (or under a higher-level parent) dynamically, you can assign an XML literal to an `XElement` instead of an `XDocument` and you can still work with your `XElement`s and `XDocument`s programmatically, e.g.:

```
Dim itemsElement = doc.Element("Items")
Dim itemToAdd = <Item ID=<%= item.Id %> Sent=<%= item.SentDate %> UoM="Each"/>
itemsElement.Add(itemToAdd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a class based approach and then using the `XmlSerializer` to create the xml.  Using classes makes the code easier to read and write, IMO.

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization

Sub Main

    'Create an instance of the class and populate it with data
    Dim i As New RFQsIssued()
    i.Items.Add(New Item With {.ID = "s1600", .Sent = DateTime.Now, .UoM = "Each"})
    i.Items.Add(New Item With {.ID = "54332", .Sent = DateTime.Now, .UoM = "Each"})

    'Create an instance of the serializer and use it to create an xml file.
    'This could also be a memory stream instead of a StreamWriter.
    Dim xSer As New XmlSerializer(i.GetType())
    Using wrt As New StreamWriter("c:\test\testVB.xml")
        xSer.Serialize(wrt, i)
    End Using

    'Read the contents of the file and display to the console.
    Dim result As String = File.ReadAllText("c:\test\testVB.xml")

    Console.WriteLine(result)
End Sub

Public Class RFQsIssued

    Public Property Items As List(Of Item)

    Public Sub New()
        Me.Items = New List(Of Item)()
    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Item
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property ID As String
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property Sent As DateTime
    <XmlAttribute>
    Public Property UoM As String
End Class
```